# Flutter web - dio changes post requests into options requests

Tags: flutter, http, dart, flutter-web, dio

I'm using `package:dio` in a Flutter web application.

Whenever I send a POST request, however, it gets changed into an OPTIONS request. The function that makes the API request looks like this:

```dart
Future<LoginResponse> login(LoginRequest request) async {
    final dio = Dio(BaseOptions(baseUrl: "http://localhost:8000"));
    final response = await dio.post("/login", data: request.toJson());
    return LoginResponse.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.data));
}
```

This code sends an `OPTIONS` request to `http://localhost:8000/login`. If I add that endpoint to my server, it works.

If I send the POST request from postman manually it also works.

If I change this code to other methods (e.g. `dio.delete(...)`) it also maps to an `OPTIONS` request.

Why is `dio` rewriting my requests?

Comment: It's not the Dart code that's doing that, it's the browser. It's doing a CORS preflight. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Preflight_request The browser does this before sending the real request to check that the server is going to respond with the correct CORS header.

Comment: Thanks, that solved my problem :)

Comment: @cameron1024 how did you fixe it?

Comment: I modified the server to accept an OPTIONS request to the same endpoint. The link Richard posted in the first comment shows what request the browser makes first. If your server doesn't respond to that OPTIONS request, the next GET/POST/etc request will fail

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar problem with a POST request to Sanic webserver.

The solution was to add the `@cross_origin()` decorator from the `sanic_cors` package.

Example:

```py
from sanic_cors import cross_origin
from sanic import Sanic
from sanic.response import json
from sanic.blueprints import Blueprint

app = Sanic(__name__)
endpoint = Blueprint('Test', '/test')
app.blueprint(endpoint)


@endpoint.route("/", methods=['POST', 'OPTIONS'])
@cross_origin(endpoint)
async def schranktyp(request):
    return json({'message': 'OK'})


def main():
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=8000, debug=True)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Maybe this will help someone in the future.